# View lost when refreshing ObjectDataProvider

Tags: wpf, view, objectdataprovider

I'm implementing a textbox filter on a list based on Josh Smith's example at http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/12/searching-for-items-in-a-listbox. Basically, it sets the Filter on the view to a delegate that checks against the text in the search box. I hook up the filter like so:

```
var pickerView = FindResource("sortedRulesView") as CollectionViewSource;
new TextSearchFilter(pickerView.View, SearchTextBox);
```

Later, when I refresh the ObjectDataProvider, the filter is lost. I've noticed that pickerView.View has a different hashcode after the refresh. Are all the views recreated when the data refreshes? Does that mean I should reattach the filter again whenever I call ObjectDataProvider.Refresh()? Is there some smarter way to install this filter that wouldn't require babysitting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right in saying that CollectionViewSource.View will be replaced when CollectionViewSource.Source is set.

The solution is to use the [CollectionViewSource.Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter.aspx) event instead of the [CollectionView.Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.filter.aspx) property.  This will stick around when your View goes away.

You can do this with minimal changes to Josh Smith's [TextSearchFilter](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/12/searching-for-items-in-a-listbox/) class:

```
public class TextSearchFilter
{
    public TextSearchFilter( 
        CollectionViewSource filteredView, 
        TextBox textBox )
    {
        string filterText = "";

        filteredView.Filter += delegate( object obj, FilterEventArgs e )                
        {
            if( String.IsNullOrEmpty( filterText ) )
                e.Accepted = true;

            string str = e.Item as string;
            if( String.IsNullOrEmpty( str ) )
                e.Accepted = false;

            int index = str.IndexOf(
                filterText,
                0,
                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase );

            e.Accepted = index > -1;
        };          

        textBox.TextChanged += delegate
        {
            filterText = textBox.Text;
            filteredView.View.Refresh();
        };
    }
}
```

Your hookup code then becomes:

```
var pickerView = FindResource("sortedRulesView") as CollectionViewSource;
new TextSearchFilter(pickerView, SearchTextBox);
```